# Dynamic import javascript library

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS 2 and I want to import dynamically my javascript library which is vue-slick-carousel so I made a function to do that :

```
vueSlickCarousel: () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ 'vue-slick-carousel')
```

But I also have to import the css of the library and I can't do that in the function or I haven't found how to do it so I put it at the beginning of my javascript file

```
// Vue Slick
import 'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css';

export default {
    name: "CalendarComponent",
    props: ['value', 'isOpenSaturdayMorning', 'isOpenSaturdayAfternoon'],
    components: {
        vueSlickCarousel: () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ 'vue-slick-carousel'),
    },
```

How can I make a function that import dynamically both javascript and css file of the library ?